# reloadData on tableView crashes when used with uisplitviewController inside a tabbar controller

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5.1

I am working with a tabbar application. In one of the tabs I have a tableView controller embedded as a SplitView. When this tab becomes active i make a URL call to fetch some data from the server. I am not able to populate the data in the tableView. I have tried '[self.tableView reloadData]' but the application crashes. My ViewController class is subclassed to UITableViewController.

```
- (void)didReceiveUserListFromServer
{
NSData *jsonData = responseData;
NSError *error=nil;

NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
userDetailsArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"userDetails"];
NSLog(@"count===%d",[userDetailsArray count]);   //This returns a non-zero number
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [userDetailsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReturningPatientSearchResultCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}



NSMutableDictionary *singleUserDetail = [userDetailsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text=[singleUserDetail objectForKey:@"Name"];  //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you log the value of `singleUserDetail` or `userDetailsArray` just before the crash?

Comment: @PhillipMills It crashes without logging any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try making the `userDetailsArray` a **strong** property in your class and using `self.userDetailsArray` for setting its value and references to it.

(It's odd that the array is valid for `count` and not for a later access but released memory seems like the most logical explanation.)

You can also try turning on zombies for your build scheme and see if that provides better information.